# Do app updates overwrite the app's home directory?

Tags: ios

I use the `NSHomeDirectory()` function to get the app's home folder, and write to the Documents directory within that.  I'm curious, though, what happens when the user downloads an update for the app from the App Store?  Will it all be deleted?  When I delete the app on the device, then reinstall it, it's wiped out.  So, I'm curious to know what will happen with an update.  I can't find this in the documentation at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stuff inside `~/Documents/` and the user preferences are preserved during update.

See the [iOS File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12).